# QToolButton autoRaise not working for Mac OSX

Tags: qt

I have set QToolButton::autoRaise = true -- this works for Windows but not for Mac OSX
This will make the flat buttons appear to raise as hover it with mouse...

I know that there is limitation with QToolButton on Mac OSX.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbutton.html#autoRaise-prop

Is there anyways to work around this issue?

Comment: Probably not. When certain styles are ignored by platforms its usually because the platform uses a native widget that determines the behavior. Its the same way as how OSX takes over the menuBar

Answer (score 1):

Because that property is Style-dependent, and the MacStyle uses native properties that in this case ignore the autoRaise property, your only option is to do everything for the button with stylesheets:

```
button = QtGui.QPushButton("FOO")
button.setFlat(True)
button.setStyleSheet("""
    QPushButton {
         border: 2px solid #8f8f91;
         border-radius: 6px;
         background-color: #dadbde;
         min-width: 80px;
     }

    QPushButton:pressed {
        background-color: qlineargradient(
            x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
            stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa
        );
    }

    QPushButton:hover {
        border: 2px solid blue;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
""")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.. and you need to add these to the style sheet for Mac OSX to work and behave similar to the Windows:

```
QToolButton:checked
{
    background-color: rgb(175,175,175);
}

QToolButton
{
    background-color: transparent;
}

QToolButton:hover
{
        background-color: rgb(175,175,175);
}
```